# Remove comment markup generated by a v-if condition

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

want to remove the conditional comment markup (  ) from the HTML

I am using a condition for example

```
<sidebar v-if="showSidebarTrigger"> ... </sidebar>
```

when the condition is false in dom  generated i wanted that to remove

[image: 'eg']

Comment: Downvoters - Please prefer to put comment whenever you downvote question/answer, it helps people to understand what's wrong and can modify their mistakes- Else people feel less confident and hesitate to ask anything or contribute next time. And community is not intend to make people lose their confident.

Answer (score 5):

This is what I found said by Evan You on related [Github issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/5117)

`v-if` is usually used for elements in a relatively stable node structure, rendering it to empty comment tags makes vnode lists diffing more efficient as the lists are more "stable", and it avoids some edge cases when elements are not keyed.

As stated in the statement further- a related workaround will work here - you can use`v-for` as an alternative if you don't want lots of such comment tags in DOM.

Make `computed` property say `displaySideBar` and push your `showSidebarTrigger` conditionally in `array` and return it.

```
displaySideBar() {
let showSideBar = []
  if(showSidebarTrigger) {
    showSideBar.push(showSidebarTrigger)
  }
}
```

Now in your html section

```
<div v-for="(sideBar, index) in displaySideBar" :key="`sideBar-${index}`">
   <h1> Hey </h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

a (hackish) workaround would be to set a `<template v-else />` after your `<sidebar v-if="showSidebarTrigger"> ... </sidebar>`